# Microwaving versus steaming a Christmas pudding

Tags: everyday-life

A slightly belated question on the Christmas theme: a Christmas pudding that you might buy from a supermarket can be reheated by one of two methods:

1. Microwaving for 2 minutes at 900 W.
2. Steaming for 2h30.

Why is it 75 times faster to reheat the pudding by microwaving than by steaming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steam heating requires convection to the outside boundary of the pudding. Convection is a fairly slow, inefficient process. This heat then needs to conduct through the pudding, to heat it through.

Microwave heating is much more efficient. Heat is transferred from the oven to the outer layers of the pudding with near $\text{100 %}$ efficiency. It then conducts through the pudding into the center.

If you compare the heating times for convenient foods using either microwave or air oven, you'll find microwave heating is systematically much faster.

Comment: As I understand it, microwave ovens are slightly de-tuned from the relevant absorption line of water, reducing efficiency of heating the outer layer, but enabling the EM wave to penetrate deeper into the food being heated. I don't know what the typical penetration depth is.

Comment: That's possible but absorption of the UHF energy is mainly by water, as evidenced by the almost non-absorption of dry, non-polar materials like PE, PP etc. My experience even with industrial UHFs (for the curing of rubber e.g.) is that heating proceeds mainly from the outside to the inside.

Comment: I guess it depends what you mean by "the outer layer", but, as shown by the soup experiment you mentioned in a comment on the other answer the useful heating zone is at least ~25 mm deep. And that's probably just the depth to ~25 or 50% absorption, not to near-complete absorption.

Comment: Hmmm... I said nothing about depth of the 'outer layer'. It looks more like about 10 mm to me. I also believe that 'de-tuning' UHF ovens from the line of water will simply make them less efficient. Another bit of evidence is the following: try defrosting a steak in a MW oven: you sadly end up cooking the outside...

Comment: You can  use one EoM for $x$ and one for $y$. Then you can calculate any angles.